# Successfully close dialog in another process

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, win32-process

I have a question. The problem is that I have another process which invoked ShowDialog() method, I need to close this dialog from another process but I need to close it with returning DialogResult.OK.

So from my .net program(another process) I want to close it successfully. I tried to use winapi to solve this problem, tried EndDialog function, but it returns error that ACCESS_DENIED. Tried to use hooks but those return error_no_token.

I need this to start msi installer silently. I start it with /qn switch, but this damn installer has embedded action that shows dialog in any case. I tried to close this window with sendmessage function, but in this case installer says that it is error, and rolls back the install process. I can fill all the values programmatically and click OK button on the dialog, but it requires to fill ALL THE VALUES, and there are lots of them, so it is time consuming. The purpose of this dialog is to create config file, which I can create manually later, after installation.

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but look at some way of getting the window handle and 'high-jacking' it somehow?

Comment: As i said I've been doing such things, but i can't close it successfully. It closes the window and installer "thinks" there was error cause dialog result is not OK.

Comment: As I said earlier, there are values(textboxes) in dialog box that user need to fill, only when ALL VALUES FILLED i can press OK button, but I don't want to write some low level code that fills every textbox. I want to try to close it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the main issue you are having is doing a end-run around the validation for the text fields. As you said you would be editing the configuration files later just put some dummy values in each box and click the OK the way that causes the validation to happen.

Comment: Thought about that, and if there is no answer to my question, I will try to do that. I just don't like to write code that searches some controls and then put some values there. Searching for buttons, try to click it. I had been working with winapi for a long time, and there are always lots of issues with such workarounds. Concrete solution is to force close the window with result i want, but as i see there is no simple way to do this. I can try to use dll injection, but this is also not the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to change a bad design to remove the need to do a hard task, rather then keep fighting the system.

A UI is owned by one process, and apart from automating tests, should only be changed by that process or the user.

Comment: Sometimes you have a task that you SHOULD finish :) and when any workaround is accepted to please a customer :) The installer is not ours and we can't change it :(

Answer (score 1):

There used to be installer toolkits aims at system admins, that would watch the registry and file system while running a installer and then create a custom MSI file to automate the process.   This may be another way for you to go.

Comment: I know, used MSI Studio, but there is a requirement that we need to use provided msi installer.